# Include files using condition of session

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I have 4 types of users in my system. So i have to include header files using conditions.

I tried below code.

```
if($this->session->userdata('email_admin')){
     include('header_admin.php');
}
if($this->session->userdata('email_zone_manager')){
     include('header_zone_manager.php');
}
if($this->session->userdata('email_state_manager')){
     include('header_state_manager.php');
}
if($this->session->userdata('email_user')){
    include('header_user.php');
}
```

When i tried with echo something and exit() its working means condition works file but header css and js etc. are not including.

```
   if($this->session->userdata('email_admin'))
   {    
        echo "Admin";
        include('header_admin.php');
   }
```

Above code echo "Admin" but header_admin's contents are not including.

Comment: I did not vote you down. Just a note when loading views I would use codeigniter `$this->load->view('some_file')`  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views and you can into views also.

Comment: you have to add extension of file `include('header_admin.php');`

Comment: Check your session data also make sure set

Comment: Yes brother i always use $this->load->view('some_files') But just now i'm in view and for loading that view i have to put condition that if user's session is set than user's header. Is there any other option for checking that condition that please suggest me. because condition also satisfied and files not including and views are also not loading.

Comment: @DesertP. thank you for that but i just edited my question it was my mistake while posting that code on SO in my file it's header_admin.php.

Comment: @Bhavin you can also load view from view as the same way that you load in controller.

Comment: @wolfgang1983. just figure it out that. old views are working but if i add new views in controller also those are not working so may be there is some cache issue in codeigniter. So is there any problem regarding cache in CI ?

Comment: check view file permissions

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap. Yeah nice answer iit was the problem after first version of project all the folders permissions are changed to only read no write.  Thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 2):

You can load views like this...

```
if(isset($this->session->userdata('email_admin'))){
     $this->load->view('header_admin');
}
if(isset($this->session->userdata('email_zone_manager'))){
     $this->load->view('header_zone_manager');
}
if(isset($this->session->userdata('email_state_manager'))){
     $this->load->view('header_state_manager');

}
if(isset($this->session->userdata('email_user'))){
     $this->load->view('email_user');

}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply i know that we can load view but the problem is that files are not including as well as views are also not loading in my view.

Comment: did you check that the respective session's variables are set?

Comment: Yes i check it with print_r($this->session->userdata); and all the session variables has been set.

Comment: try using `isset()`.

Comment: is header_user.php and other file are in view folder or in any subfolder?

Comment: session returns false and true so isset() is also not works i also tried with that.  main problem with it that files not including and views are not loading

Comment: i just figure it out that. Old views are working but if i add new views in controller also those are not working so may be there is some cache issue in codeigniter. So is there any problem regarding cache in CI ?

Comment: @DesertP. All are in view folder just now there is no subfolder.

Comment: if cache is your problem then `$this->output->delete_cache();` see more..https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

Comment: just run `$this->output->delete_cache();` on your page including above code

Comment: @HikmatSijapati . the problem was after first version of project all the folders permissions are changed to only read no write. Thank you for the time :)

Comment: welcome...and enjoy with codeigniter....if answer is useful accept it thank you.